# Refer to a file in the source tree in another package in a build rule

Tags: bazel

I have a build pipeline that needs to, in various places, transform data and then embed the transformed data into C++ source.  In the past, this has been done manually.  For example, we have some textproto files that get encoded using protoc and then embedded into a source file using xxd.  My task is to automate this by adding it to our build system.

I'm starting with the textproto -> encoded proto -> embed into C++ source flow.  Accordingly, I want to create two rules (forgive me if my nomenclature is incorrect---I'm a Bazel newbie):

1. encode_textproto(textproto, protofile, message) which would encode the textproto file represented by `textproto` as the message `message` found in the protofile `protofile', and,
2. cc_embed_binary_data(datafile) which would create a pair of header and source files from the data in `datafile`.

I defined the rule encode_textproto like so:

```
def strip_extension(f):
    return f.basename[:len(f.basename) - len(f.extension) - 1]

def change_extension(f, new_ext):
    return strip_extension(f) + new_ext

def _impl(ctx):
    tools, tool_manifest = ctx.resolve_tools(tools = [ctx.attr._tool])

    encoded = ctx.actions.declare_file(
        change_extension(ctx.file.textproto, ".encoded"),
        sibling = ctx.file.textproto,
    )
    all_outs = [encoded]
    args = [
        "--encode=%s" % ctx.attr.proto,
        ctx.file.protofile.path,
        "<",
        ctx.file.textproto.path,
        ">",
        encoded.path,
    ]
    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = all_outs,
        inputs = [ctx.file.textproto],
        executable = ctx.executable._tool,
        arguments = args,
        tools = tools,
        mnemonic = "EncodeTextProto",
        use_default_shell_env = False,
        input_manifests = tool_manifest,
    )

    return DefaultInfo(
        files = depset(all_outs),
        runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = all_outs),
    )

encode_textproto = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    doc = "foo",
    attrs = {
        "_tool": attr.label(
            default = Label("@com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf//:protoc"),
            allow_single_file = True,
            doc = "The tool used to generate the C++ code.",
            executable = True,
            cfg = "host",
        ),
        "textproto": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            doc = "The textproto file to encode.",
        ),
        "protofile": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            doc = "The proto file defining the proto being encoded.",
        ),
        "proto": attr.string(
            doc = "The full name of the proto message.",
        ),
    },
)
```

In our source tree we have protofiles in a proto directory foo/bar/proto and textprotos in a parallel directory foo/bar/data.  So, in foo/bar/data:BUILD.bazel I would have a stanza like:

```
encode_textproto(name = "encoded_data",
                 textproto = "data.textproto",
                 message = "foo.bar.Message",
                 protofile = "//foo/bar/proto:message.proto")
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error:  Could not make proto path relative: foo/bar/message.proto: No such file or directory.   Running with sandbox_debug, I see that the commandline being executed seems correct:

```
/home/cesc/.cache/bazel/_bazel_cesc/install/7ebdb6373cb28848a230741519affc6a/linux-sandbox -t 15 -w /home/cesc/.cache/bazel/_bazel_cesc/63327e3faffaf439c95305e1592c6182/sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/execroot/work -w /tmp -w /dev/shm -S /home/cesc/.cache/bazel/_bazel_cesc/63327e3faffaf439c95305e1592c6182/sandbox/linux-sandbox/4/stats.out -D -- bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf/protoc '--encode=foo.bar.Message' foo/bar/proto/message.proto '<' foo/bar/data/data.textproto '>' bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo/bar/data/data.encoded
```

I've tried creating a filegroup in //foo/bar/proto that exports the proto, assuming that the root cause was that //foo/bar/proto:message.proto was not visible to //foo/bar/data:**pkg**.

```
filegroup(
    name = "protos",
    srcs = glob(["*.proto"])
    visibility = ["//foo/bar/data:__pkg__],
)
```

and then change the encode_textproto's protofile attribute to "//foo/bar/proto:protos".  (This fails even if there is a single proto message, and there are a *lot* of protos so I'd prefer to glob where possible.)  This also fails:

```
ERROR: /home/cesc/work/foo/bar/data/BUILD.bazel:7:17: in protofile attribute of encode_textproto rule //foo/bar/data:encoded_data: '//foo/bar/proto:protos' must produce a single file
```

So I'm not sure how to proceed (I've also tried exports_files with similar results).  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `protofile` is not being included as an input; the `ctx.actions.run` call needs to be amended to something like this:

```
       inputs = [ctx.file.textproto, ctx.file.protofile],
```